# Is there any way I could download a iphone app to my mac book pro?

Tags: iphone, applications

I want to be a able to download the amino app to my macbook but it has not been made to be able to do that but I would like to know if I could in some way

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been answered before in this [thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113935/is-it-possible-to-install-an-iphone-app-in-macbook-pro).

The general reason is that the code is compiled for an ARM CPU (iPhone, Samsung, Pixel, etc).  Your MacBook has an Intel CPU and the code instructions are different.  As a developer, there is a simulator in Xcode to develop a mobile application with, but the simulator is not really for use to obtain an application from the App store and run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the app easily using iTunes. But you can't run it on your Mac, which I suspect is what you really want to do. As far as your Mac is concerned, it's just a binary data file, not an executable program.